# C# Enumerator Assign Value

Tags: c#

Want to assign few values to IEnumerableshort.

```
IEnumerable<short> someValues= ????
```

Expected o/p : someValues = 0,1,2,3

Comment: `IEnumerable<short> someValues= new short[]{0,1,2,3};`

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(Convert.ToInt16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   IEnumerable<short> shortValues = new short[] { 3,6}         

  IEnumerable<int> Values = from value in Enumerable.Range(1, 10) select value;
```

you can try this .

Comment: 1.This doesn't returns what op asks. 2.It returns `IEnumerable<int>` not `IEnumerable<short>`. 3. sql query syntax is redundant, you can just say `Enumerable.Range(1, 10);`, both are same. 4. If op needs numbers which are non sequential, this can't help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel So how about your write your suggestion in an answer, instead of a comment, so it will help the OP and also future searchers on the site?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I'm ashamed to write it as an answer as it is very small to fit into an answer. But yes, it is an answer, it answers the question. OP should have done some research effort before taking the effort to ask the question here. If anyone is interested, they can add it as an answer. I'll upvote it.

Comment: Was thinking why did i get an down vote because did i get stuck between the war of words between Sriram & Avner.. fyi have updated my answer too.

Answer (score 3):

String:

```
IEnumerable<string> m_oEnum = new string[]{"1","2","3"};
```

Int:

```
IEnumerable<int> m_oEnum = new int[]{ 1,2,3};
```

Short:

```
IEnumerable<short> m_oEnum = new short[]{ 1,2,3};
```

object:

```
class Book
{
public string val1{get;set;}
public string val2{get;set;}
.
.
}

IEnumerable<Book> books = new List<Book>();
```